# Access django dict through shell after aggregate annotate

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-orm, django-shell

Simple question
I am trying to get the result of an aggregate to use in my view to make a simple calculation.

I have written the following.

```
sms_raised = SmsBacker.objects.values('amount').annotate(Sum('amount'))
sms_raised
[{'amount': 150L, 'amount__sum': 600}]
```

How do I access those values in the shell.

I have tried

```
sms_raised_amount
sms_raised__amount
sms_raised.amount
```

All with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dict is the first item in the list, so

```
sms_raised[0]['amount']
sms_raised[0]['amount__sum']
```